# How to sum specific columns while keeping the unique ID without nan

Tags: python, pandas

So my dataframe is-

```
Name   ID   A B C   
Sam    11   1 1 1    
Sam    nan  0 1 4         
Dan    12   1 4 4     
Dan    nan  1 5 0     
Dan    12   2 4 4                            
Tom    15   1 4 6
```

I want to create an output containing-

```
Name ID Total     
Sam  11  8    
Dan  12  25        
Tom  15  11
```

While I do groupby Name and ID. I get Sam and Dan twice for its null ID. How do I aggregate there A,B,C and get there unique ID as there final output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
# First make dataframe with names and total scores.
df['Total'] = df['A'] + df['B'] + df['C']    
df_names = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Name')['Total'].sum())

# Then make dataframe that has the IDs.
df_ID = pd.DataFrame(df[['Name', 'ID']].dropna())
df_ID.set_index('Name', inplace=True)

# Then add in the IDs to the dataframe with total scores.
df_names['ID'] = df_ID.drop_duplicates()
```

Now `df_names` is the final dataframe you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks I tried your code but for some reason Name column gets dropped from the dataframe.

Comment: It should be the index in the new dataframe, not a column.

Comment: Hi, I tried adding - pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Name')['Total'].sum().reset_index() and this keeps the Name column in the dataframe. Thank you so much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Great, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

```
out = (df.drop("ID", axis=1)
         .groupby(["Name", df.ID.ffill(downcast="infer")], sort=False)
         .sum()
         .sum(axis=1)
         .to_frame("Total"))
```

First drop the `ID` column (but not in-place) to ignore it in the summation, then group by the `Name` and the forward-filled `ID` and sum the in-group values. Then sum all the column values to get the total and turn it into a dataframe with column `Total`

to get

```
>>> out

         Total
Name ID
Sam  11      8
Dan  12     25
Tom  15     11
```

`downcast=infer` helps keep the `ID`s integer after forward-filling and `sort=False` keeps the order in the dataframe while grouping.

Comment: Thanks, Your method works but its breaks down is my ID column is named as "Agent ID". It seems like it need one one word rather then a phrase.